# Statistical accumulator in Python

Tags: python, oop, statistics, accumulator

An statistical accumulator allows one to perform incremental calculations. For instance, for computing the arithmetic mean of a stream of numbers given at arbitrary times one could make an object which keeps track of the current number of items given, `n` and their sum, `sum`. When one requests the mean, the object simply returns `sum/n`.

An accumulator like this allows you to compute incrementally in the sense that, when given a new number, you don't need to recompute the entire sum and count.

Similar accumulators can be written for other statistics (cf. [boost library](http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/libs/accumulators/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_accumulators_framework) for a C++ implementation).

How would you implement accumulators in Python? [The code I came up with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771424/python-average-tabular-data-help) is:

```
class Accumulator(object):
    """
    Used to accumulate the arithmetic mean of a stream of
    numbers. This implementation does not allow to remove items
    already accumulated, but it could easily be modified to do
    so. also, other statistics could be accumulated.
    """
    def __init__(self):
     # upon initialization, the numnber of items currently
     # accumulated (_n) and the total sum of the items acumulated
     # (_sum) are set to zero because nothing has been accumulated
     # yet.
     self._n = 0
     self._sum = 0.0

    def add(self, item):
     # the 'add' is used to add an item to this accumulator
     try:
        # try to convert the item to a float. If you are
        # successful, add the float to the current sum and
        # increase the number of accumulated items
        self._sum += float(item)
        self._n += 1
     except ValueError:
        # if you fail to convert the item to a float, simply
        # ignore the exception (pass on it and do nothing)
        pass

    @property
    def mean(self):
     # the property 'mean' returns the current mean accumulated in
     # the object
     if self._n > 0:
        # if you have more than zero items accumulated, then return
        # their artithmetic average
        return self._sum / self._n
     else:
        # if you have no items accumulated, return None (you could
        # also raise an exception)
        return None

# using the object:

# Create an instance of the object "Accumulator"
my_accumulator = Accumulator()
print my_accumulator.mean
# prints None because there are no items accumulated

# add one (a number)
my_accumulator.add(1)
print my_accumulator.mean
# prints 1.0

# add two (a string - it will be converted to a float)
my_accumulator.add('2')
print my_accumulator.mean
# prints 1.5

# add a 'NA' (will be ignored because it cannot be converted to float)
my_accumulator.add('NA')
print my_accumulator.mean
# prints 1.5 (notice that it ignored the 'NA')
```

Interesting design questions arise:

1. How to make the accumulator
   thread-safe?
2. How to safely remove
   items?
3. How to architect in a way
   that allows other statistics to be
   plugged in easily (a factory for statistics)

Comment: What is the status on an accumulator library for python? I would like to use it with PyTables.

Answer (score 3):

For a generalized, threadsafe higher-level function, you could use something like the following in combination with the `Queue.Queue` class and some other bits:

```
from Queue import Empty

def Accumulator(f, q, storage):
    """Yields successive values of `f` over the accumulation of `q`.

    `f` should take a single iterable as its parameter.

    `q` is a Queue.Queue or derivative.

    `storage` is a persistent sequence that provides an `append` method.
    `collections.deque` may be particularly useful, but a `list` is quite acceptable.

    >>> from Queue import Queue
    >>> from collections import deque
    >>> from threading import Thread
    >>> def mean(it):
    ...     vals = tuple(it)
    ...     return sum(it) / len(it)
    >>> value_queue = Queue()
    >>> LastThreeAverage = Accumulator(mean, value_queue, deque((), 3))
    >>> def add_to_queue(it, queue):
    ...     for value in it:
    ...         value_queue.put(value)
    >>> putting_thread = Thread(target=add_to_queue,
    ...                         args=(range(0, 12, 2), value_queue))
    >>> putting_thread.start()
    >>> list(LastThreeAverage)
    [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8]
    """
    try:
        while True:
            storage.append(q.get(timeout=0.1))
            q.task_done()
            yield f(storage)
    except Empty:
        pass
```

This generator function evades most of its purported responsibility by delegating it to other entities:

- It relies on `Queue.Queue` to supply its source elements in a thread-safe manner
- A `collections.deque` object can be passed in as the value of the `storage` parameter; this provides, among other things, a convenient way to only use the last `n` (in this case 3) values
- The function itself (in this case `mean`) is passed as a parameter.  This will result in less-than-optimally efficient code in some cases, but is readily applied to all sorts of situations.

Note that there is a possibility of the accumulator timing out if your producer thread takes longer than 0.1 seconds per value.  This is easily remedied by passing a longer timeout or by removing the timeout parameter entirely.  In the latter case the function will block indefinitely at the end of the queue; this usage makes more sense in a case where it's being used in a sub thread (usually a `daemon` thread).  Of course you can also parametrize the arguments that are passed to `q.get` as a fourth argument to `Accumulator`.

If you want to communicate end of queue, i.e. that there are no more values to come, from the producer thread (here `putting_thread`), you can pass and check for a sentinel value or use some other method.  There is more info in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605188/communicating-end-of-queue); I opted to write a subclass of Queue.Queue called [CloseableQueue](http://github.com/intuited/CloseableQueue) that provides a `close` method.

There are various other ways you could customize the behaviour of such a function, for example by limiting the queue size; this is just an example of usage.

#### edit

As mentioned above, this loses some efficiency because of the necessity of recalculation and also, I think, doesn't really answer your question.

A generator function can also accept values through its `send` method.  So you can write a mean generator function like

```
def meangen():
    """Yields the accumulated mean of sent values.

    >>> g = meangen()
    >>> g.send(None) # Initialize the generator
    >>> g.send(4)
    4.0
    >>> g.send(10)
    7.0
    >>> g.send(-2)
    4.0
    """
    sum = yield(None)
    count = 1
    while True:
        sum += yield(sum / float(count))
        count += 1
```

Here the yield expression is both bringing values —the arguments to `send`— into the function, while simultaneously passing the calculated values out as the return value of `send`.

You can pass the generator returned by a call to that function to a more optimizable accumulator generator function like this one:

```
def EfficientAccumulator(g, q):
    """Similar to Accumulator but sends values to a generator `g`.

    >>> from Queue import Queue
    >>> from threading import Thread
    >>> value_queue = Queue()
    >>> g = meangen()
    >>> g.send(None)
    >>> mean_accumulator = EfficientAccumulator(g, value_queue)
    >>> def add_to_queue(it, queue):
    ...     for value in it:
    ...         value_queue.put(value)
    >>> putting_thread = Thread(target=add_to_queue,
    ...                         args=(range(0, 12, 2), value_queue))
    >>> putting_thread.start()
    >>> list(mean_accumulator)
    [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
    """
    try:
        while True:
            yield(g.send(q.get(timeout=0.1)))
            q.task_done()
    except Empty:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing this in Python, there are two things I would do differently:

1. Separate out the functionality of each accumulator.
2. Not use @property in any way you did.

For the first one, I would likely want to come up with an API for performing an accumulation, perhaps something like:

```
def add(self, num) # add a number
def compute(self) # compute the value of the accumulator
```

Then I would create a AccumulatorRegistry that holds onto these accumulators, and allows the user to call actions and add to all of them. The code may look like:

```
class Accumulators(object):
    _accumulator_library = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.accumulator_library = {}
        for key, value in Accumulators._accumulator_library.items():
            self.accumulator_library[key] = value()

    @staticmethod
    def register(name, accumulator):
        Accumulators._accumulator_library[name] = accumulator

    def add(self, num):
        for accumulator in self.accumulator_library.values():
            accumulator.add(num)

    def compute(self, name):
        self.accumulator_library[name].compute()

    @staticmethod
    def register_decorator(name):
        def _inner(cls):
            Accumulators.register(name, cls)
            return cls


@Accumulators.register_decorator("Mean")
class Mean(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0
        self.count = 0

    def add(self, num):
        self.count += 1
        self.total += num

    def compute(self):
        return self.total / float(self.count)
```

I should probably speak to your thread-safe question. Python's GIL protects you from a lot of threading issues. There are a few things you may way to do to protect yourself though:

- If these objects are localized to one thread, use threading.local
- If not, you can wrap the operations in a lock, using the with context syntax to deal with holding the lock for you.

Comment: Great idea about the `register` - I agree that my initial example is too experimental. I look forward to further comments. Thanks.

Comment: I should also note that I'm making use of python 2.6+ features ;)