# single iteration sharing the iterator

Tags: python, iterator

I have a lot of data, usually in a file. I want to compute some quantities so I have this kind of functions:

```
def mean(iterator):
    n = 0
    sum = 0.
    for i in iterator:
      sum += i
      n += 1
    return sum / float(n)
```

I have also many other similar functions (`var`, `size`, ...)

Now I have an iterator iterating throught the data: `iter_data`. I can compute all the quantities I want: `m = mean(iter_data); v = var(iter_data)` and so on, but the problem is that I am iterating many times and this is expensive in my case. Actually the I/O is the most expensive part.

So the question is: can I compute my quantities `m, v, ...` iterating *only one time* over `iter_data` *keeping separate* the functions `mean`, `var`, ...  so that it is easy to add new ones?

What I need is something similar to [boost::accumulators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/accumulators/)

Comment: http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html

Comment: You could bundle all your functions into one function with one loop and return a dictionary of all the computed values, like `{'mean':2.7, 'var':0.2, 'size':27}`, etc.

Comment: @MrE: no, in your solution your are not keeping separate the function, but you are computing the mean and the variance in the same function

Comment: @Brionius, same problem. As I said in the question: *keeping separate* the functions

Comment: is your data too big to fit into memory? Otherwise iterating will probably be fast and you can use e.g. numpy.

Comment: @dastrobu: in general no, it is too big

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If you iterate only one time, you will have to share data between the functions. If you cannot share the data, you will need to iterate multiple times either over either the original or a cached copy of it.

Comment: @Blender: who said I cannot share data between the functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Statistical accumulator in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774315/statistical-accumulator-in-python)

Comment: You should really consider using python data analysis tools like numpy and pandas to process your data. Here is how to do it in pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once

Comment: @Bound: I think pandas is keeping data in memory

Answer (score 5):

For example use objects and callbacks like:

```
class Counter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0
    def __call__(self, i):
        self.n += 1

class Summer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sum = 0
    def __call__(self, i):
        self.sum += i


def process(iterator, callbacks):
    for i in iterator:
        for f in callbacks: f(i)

counter = Counter()
summer = Summer()
callbacks = [counter, summer]
iterator = xrange(10) # testdata
process(iterator, callbacks)

# process results from callbacks
n = counter.n
sum = summer.sum
```

This is easily extendible and iterates the data only once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.tee`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and generator magic (I say magic because it's not exactly nice and readable):

```
import itertools

def mean(iterator):
    n = 0
    sum = 0.
    for i in iterator:
         sum += i
         n += 1
         yield
    yield sum / float(n)

def multi_iterate(funcs, iter_data):
    iterators = itertools.tee(iter_data, len(funcs))
    result_iterators = [func(values) for func, values in zip(funcs, iterators)]
    for results in itertools.izip(*result_iterators):
        pass
    return results

mean_result, var_result = multi_iterate([mean, var], iter([10, 20, 30]))

print(mean_result)    # 20.0
```

By the way, you can write `mean` in a simpler way:

```
def mean(iterator):
    total = 0.
    for n, item in enumerate(iterator, 1):
         total += i
         yield
    yield total / n
```

You shouldn't name variables `sum` because that shadows the built-in function with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Without classes, you could adapt the following:

```
def my_mean():
    total = 0.
    length = 0
    while True:
        val = (yield)
        if val is not None:
            total += val
            length += 1
        else:
            yield total / length

def my_len():
    length = 0
    while True:
        val = (yield)
        if val is not None:
            length += 1
        else:
            yield length

def my_sum():
    total = 0.
    while True:
        val = (yield)
        if val is not None:
            total += val
        else:
            yield total


def process(iterable, **funcs):
    fns = {name:func() for name, func in funcs.iteritems()}
    for fn in fns.itervalues():
        fn.send(None)
    for item in iterable:
        for fn in fns.itervalues():
            fn.send(item)
    return {name:next(func) for name, func in fns.iteritems()}


data = [1, 2, 3]
print process(data, items=my_len, some_other_value=my_mean, Total=my_sum)
# {'items': 3, 'some_other_value': 2.0, 'Total': 6.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to have a main `Calc` class that iterates over the data applying different calculation for `mean`, `var`, *etc* and then can return those values through an interface.  You could make it more generic by letting calculations register themselves with this class before the main calculation and then have their results available through new accessors in the interface.